# How to give the folder name using model instance in django

Tags: python, django

New to python . Anyway I am on my way to first project.

See i need to upload multiple file into single folder so i come up with an idea like this.

```
folder_name1
------myfiles1.jpg
------myfiled2.jpg
folder_name2
------mynewfiles.jpg
------mynewfiles1.jpg
```

And  i read lot of tutorials this is my models.py

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):  
    return "uploads/{folder}/{file}".format(id=instance, folder=instance.albumname, file=filename)

class Album(models.Model):
    albumname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    audiofile = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)#documents/%Y/%m/%d
```

Updated: This is my view.py

```
def viewalbum(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AlbumForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            alubmnew = Album()
            albumvalue = Album()

            albumnew = Album(albumname = request.POST.get('albumname', None))
            albumvalue = Album(audiofile = request.FILES['audiofile'])

            #for albumvalue in request.FILES.getlist('audiofile'):
            albumvalue.save()
            albumnew.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('google.views.viewalbum'))
    else:
        form = AlbumForm()
    return render_to_response('audio/test.html',{'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The problem i am having right now is.. It doesn`t create albumname folder

And also in my form i can`t able to upload multiple file in single time. Its actually takes only one file to upload...

Comment: does it give any error messages? If it doesn't create an albumname folder, then what Does it do? Does it upload the file anywhere?

Comment: It doesn`t create folder named albumename but i m seeing no error and file uploads like uploads/filename. I have a doubt i am taking the albumname and choose file to uploads same time. Is it good ? or it ll only take db instance?

Comment: Have you set up properly MEDIA_URL??

Comment: This is a potential security risk. Assuming `albumname` comes from the user or external sources, you should never use that to construct a path to your file.

Comment: @arocks then how to do that ?

Comment: Depends on the purpose, if you are worried that the files will get overwritten then it doesn't happen at all. for e.g. if you are uploading `myfiles.jpg` and it already exists in the MEDIA_DIR, then the new file will be automatically renamed to `myfiles_1.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need alter the view like this

```
    albumvalue = Album()
    albumvalue.albumname = request.POST.get('albumname', None)
    albumvalue.audiofile = request.FILES['audiofile']
    albumvalue.save()
```

I think Manson Hanson tells the correct way to write the model.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
def content_file_name(instance, filename):   
    upload_dir = os.path.join('uploads', instance.albumname)  
    if not os.path.exists(upload_dir):
        os.makedirs(upload_dir)
    return os.path.join(upload_dir, filename)
```

Comment: I tried yours same thing its creating uploads and inside the filename coming instead of the albumname. may be my somewhere in my code hav the problem.

Comment: than u may check by the old way. Debug or print the albumname inside content_file_name function

Comment: if i am giving like this return "uploads/{id}/{file}".format(id=instance, file=filename) It will create the uploads/Album object/file name is there ...

Comment: Ok ... If sometime instead of the folder Album object, Its creating None folder

Comment: ok using pprint.pprint(instance.albumname) give me u'' nothing. what can i d now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import os
def content_file_name(instance, filename):  
    return os.path.join('uploads/%s' % instance.albumname, filename)
```

Does this crate the albumname folder?

Comment: No that`s not creating the folder

Comment: @gello where does the file upload to when you make this the return statement? Also, are you sure the instance HAS an albumname to begin with? Can you show us the view which creates an Album object?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check the instance

Comment: if i am giving like this return "uploads/{id}/{file}".format(id=instance, file=filename) It will create the uploads/Album object/file name is there ...

Comment: Ok ... If sometime instead of the folder Album object, Its creating None folde